# ¿Cómo hacer para que no cree un registro cuando hay una respuesta 4xx ó 5xx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo una api con la siguiente ruta **POST** `/carros`

en el controlador tengo:

*app/controllers/api/v1/carros_controller.rb*

```
module API
  module V1
    class CarrosController < ApplicationController
      skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
      def create
        @carro = Carro.new
        @carro.marca = 'chevrolet'
        @carro.modelo = 'impala'
        @carro.color = 'azul'
        @carro.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

En la vista tengo el siguiente jbuilder:

*app/views/api/v1/carros/create.json.jbuilder*

```
json.ok true
json.carro do
  json.marca  @carro.marca
  json.modelo @carro.modelo
  json.color  @carro.color
end
```

El carro se genera bien, con todas sus validaciones y la salida `jbuilder` también sin problemas, pero en el header puede faltar un parámetro y arrojar como resultado una respueta ***406 Not Acceptable***, aún con esta respuesta igual crea el carro, lo que quiero es ¿Cómo hacer para que si hay una respuesta 4xx 0 500 no cree el carro?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me queda la duda que tu 406 sea por falta de un parámetro. En general eso suele ser un [422](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422) y es un estado agregado por el programador como respuesta, no retornada por el framework.
Para resolver un 406, creo que deberías definir los formatos válidos de respuesta. Hay varias formas, una es definiendo el formato para tu action específico:

```
  def create
    @carro = Carro.new
    @carro.marca = 'chevrolet'
    @carro.modelo = 'impala'
    @carro.color = 'azul'
    @carro.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json
    end
  end
```

otra, definiendo el formato de tu controlador entero:

```
module API
  module V1
    class CarrosController < ApplicationController
      skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
      respond_to :json

      def create
        #...
```

y la última, es setearlo en `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :carros, defaults: { format: :json }
```

Respecto a como hacer que con un 4xx o 5xx no te cree el carro, eso es uno de los grandes dilemas de la programación web, jaja.
Lamentablemente no hay una solución absoluta y tienes que abordar caso a caso, ya que no puedes anticipar donde se generará el próximo error. Por ejemplo, podrías englobar en el action toda la creación de tu carro junto con otros accesos a la BD dentro de una misma transacción SQL, procesó todo ok, pero en la vista tienes un error y te va a retornar 500 de todas formas habiendo creado el carro... y está bien eso, porque tu error está en la vista, no en el controlador, así que tampoco hay razón de hacer un rollback a eso. De hecho el request podría haber pasado todo bien, generar bien la vista, luego rails delega la respuesta a tu server nginx, pero este tiene un problema y va a retornar 500 de igual forma... y por esta razón no tendrías por qué deshacer el carro creado, cuando el problema ni siquiera fue de rails.